# Where to find uid (User ID) list in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the tracking pixel on a newsletter with the following URL:

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&amp;tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&amp;cid=111&amp;uid=123&amp;t=event&amp;ec=email&amp;ea=open&amp;el=111&amp;cs=newsletter&amp;cm=email&amp;cn=062413&amp;cm1=1" alt="" />
```

I can correctly see how many times the newsletter gets opened but I cannot find on Analytics where to see who actually opened it, where do I find the `uid` list in order to know who opened the email?

Comment: You must be passing User ID in custom dimension, right?

Comment: @dikesh yes I've set up the custom dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the same in `Top Events` reports.

Go to `Behaviour > Events > Top Events` and then select secondary dimension as `User ID` as below. There you will be able to see `User ID` with `Total Events`.

[image: User ID with Total Events]

Hope this helps !

Comment: thank you! I just have a problem because I can't see the ID's I pass to analytics.. In order to add the custom dimension I went to Custom Definitions--> Custom Dimensions and I've created a new dimension named User ID with scope User, but still I can't display the data. Do you have any idea if i'm missing something? Is the url correct?

Comment: URL seems correct. You have to create a separate view for User ID as mentioned in this document. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en

Comment: I've added the User ID view but still I can't see the id's :(

Comment: Try creating Custom report and check with `ga:hits`. If you have implemented this on your website, check using `omnibug` add-on, whether GA hits are being fired or not.

Comment: the hit is sent correctly, maybe It could be related to some delay?

Comment: Might be. It will take around 4-5 hours to reflect data in GA. Sometimes it can be more than that.

Comment: Ok! Ty very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to

- enable user id tracking for this ga property first
- then create a custom view
- then send data and wait

See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666

As this is not referenced from the ga protocol documentation, this is very unclear when you start to use GA